# Does any one configured jenkins & selenium for CI in force.com

Tags: jenkins, ci, selenium

Are there any tutorials for config jenkins which fires selenium to run tests.

Answer (score 4):

This has been discussed at length in [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/654/is-there-a-way-to-setup-continous-integration-for-apex-tests) -

There was a session about it at Dreamforce 2011 as well which I'd recommend viewing - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTdyiie8W_g

Another post on the DFC blog worth reading - http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/07/apex-testing-smartfactory-and-jenkins.html

Comment: Good list of resources, +1, you may also want to include this, https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools. One of things often overlooked is cleaning the org before attempting another build. If this is not done, components overtime that get deleted or renamed in source control build up in the build org and may cause tests or other strange behaviours.

Answer (score -2):

[Salesforce continuous Integration](http://www.flosum.com) is not easy for many reasons. The nature of the platform leads to many manual steps such as creation of package.xml. This is a very manual and error prone step. Watch this video for automated continuous Integration for Salesforce

Comment: looks like a product promo .. thou it is CI related its not a direct answer for jenkins / selenium configuration..