# Get Status Updates When Running Tests with ANT Migration Tool

Tags: unit-test, migration-tool, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up Jenkins to automate a daily task of running all tests in my sandbox (and eventually, production environment.

Typically, when I do a `deploy` or `retrieve` task, I get lots of output while the process in going:

```
[sf:retrieve] Request for a retrieve submitted successfully.
[sf:retrieve] Request Id for the current retrieve task: 04sJ00000005q0JIAQ
[sf:retrieve] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:retrieve] Request Status: Completed
```

However, when I do a test task, I get one line, and then a big old nothing:

```
[sf:compileAndTest] compileAndTest on https://test.salesforce.com, compiling 0 classes and 0 triggers, deleting 0 classes and 0 triggers


.
```

Furthermore, there's no evidence in my org that anything is happening:  nothing shows up on my Monitor Deployments page, and nothing shows up in my Test Execution monitoring page.  It's really disconcerting, since running all tests can take 30+ min and I have no idea how it's going (or if it's actually happening at all).

Any tips for how I can get more useful feedback?  Here's my ant target:

```
<target name="runTestsDev">
    <sequential>
        <echo>Running all tests in the "dev" environment.</echo>
        <sf:compileAndTest username="${sf.dev.username}"
                password="${sf.dev.password}"
                serverurl="${sf.testurl}">
            <runTests namespace="Default"/>
        </sf:compileAndTest>
    </sequential>
</target>
```

(It's actually more generic, and defined with macros -- just giving you the simplified version)

Comment: And just to be thorough, the following seemingly similar questions don't address my problem: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/654/is-there-a-way-to-setup-continous-integration-for-apex-tests, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/how-run-tests-in-default-namespace-for-sandbox-using-ant/12968#12968

Comment: compileAndTest will be using the [Apex API method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_calls_compileandtest.htm) of the same name. I don't think you can monitor the progress of this call. To run the tests and be able to monitor the progress you would need to create [ApexTestQueueItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm) records.

Comment: @DanielBallinger hm.  Is there support for that in the Migration Tool or another stable client?  I'm trying to do a simple setup w/ ANT.   Is there another way to run tests and get the results that I'm missing?

Comment: I guess I could deploy an empty package and choose runAllTests (although I really just want to limit it to my namespace).  Is that what others are doing for this?

Comment: I haven't spent any time with the migration tool, so I tend to think of it from what the API provides. It is certainly possible to code up a command line tool that would queue all the classes in  a namespace for testing and then monitor the progress.

Comment: Hm.  Sounds like an option.  I'm going to hold out a bit and see if anyone comes back with tips on the Migration Tool, because I'd prefer an existing tool to rolling something myself, but good to know about. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps doing a deploy marked as "Validate Only" and "Run All Tests" will provide the balance you need?

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by tweaking a few of the parameters in the deploy.  Namely `trace`, `pollWaitMillis`, `logType`, and `runTest`.  For example:

```
<target name="deploy">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" 
             password="${sf.password}" 
             serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
             maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" 
             checkOnly="true"
             runAllTests="false"
             logType="Detail"
             deployRoot="src"
             trace="true"
             pollWaitMillis="1000">
    <runTest>MyClass1</runTest>
    <runTest>MyClass2</runTest> <!--maybe you can use <runTests namespace="default">?-->
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Alternatively, you could just build a simple Apex rest webservice that queues all non-namespaced tests, and call this webserivce from Jenkins using curl & ant.  There is no harm in queuing non-test classes.  These test results would appear in the "Apex Text Execution" section of the setup menu.

```
@HttpGet    
global static ResponseBody queueTests() {
    List<ApexTestQueueItem> items = new List<ApexTestQueueItem>();
    for(ApexClass ac : [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = null]) {
        items.add(new ApexTestQueueItem(ApexClassId = ac.Id));
    }

    insert items;
    return new ResponseBody('success');
}
```

If you wanted to do this kind of thing on demand, [www.aside.io](http://www.aside.io) allows users to run unit tests by query from its "test" section.  Click the "Run Some" button, and enter the following query:

```
SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE NamespacePrefix = null
```

Comment: Run All Tests causes all the AppExchange packaged tests to run, some of which fail.  My question is "Do I have anything in my code that would fail to deploy" and so I need only my namespace to work.

Comment: Good catch, i'm meant the runTests element, will update answer.

Comment: Ideally, I wouldn't have to maintain this file with all the individual test names.  I just want to run all tests that are non-namespaced.  This is meant to be part of a chain of Jenkins jobs

Comment: Okay, added an option where you dont have to maintain the list.